# Find a recurrence relation for the amount of money

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

You have an initial amount of money saved $P$ (for principal). On this, you get an annual rate of return on an investment equal to $r$ yearly return on your investment). Assuming you don't withdraw from your savings or save any extra, the amount of money you have, $a_n$ in year $n$ is the amount you had invested in year $n - 1$ plus the interest accrued. We use the convention that $n = 0$ corresponds to the year of the initial investment, so $a_0 =P$.

I would like to know how to get the recurrence relation and  find a formula to solve for $a_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the information you gave, there are 2 key steps to do this.

> Interest

So if we have $£x$, and we receive interest at a rate of $r$, we get $£x$ (our initial investment) + $£rx$ (the interest) (here we view the investment as a decimal).
So for example, if my bank was giving me $20\%$ interest, and I invest $£20$, then in total I would have 
$£20 + £20\times0.2 = £24$.

An easier way to put this would be $£x(1+r)$.

> Recurrences

We have that $a_n$ is the money from the $n-1$- th year along with interest, from above, we have that $$a_n = a_{n-1}(1+r).$$
Along with the initial condition $a_0 = P$, we can solve this.

One general way to solve recurrence relations, is to write them out until we see a pattern emerge.

So \begin{align}
a_n &= a_{n-1}(1+r)\\
&= a_{n-2}(1+r)^2\\
&\,\vdots\\
&= a_{1}(1+r)^{n-1}\\
&= a_0(1+r)^n\\
&= P(1+r)^n.
\end{align}

Thus we have solved the recurrence!

> Recurrences with additional investment

What if I invested an additional $P$ each year? What is the recurrence equation and the formula? Is it $a_n = n P(1+r) + P$?

Not quite, let's apply the same technique. Each year, we would get interest and then also we would add in investment. 
This makes it 
$$a_n = a_{n-1}(1+r) + P.$$

By applying the same technique as above, we get that $$a_n = P \frac{(1+r)^{n+1} - 1}{r}.$$

Comment: What if I invested an additional P each year? What is the recurrence equation and the formula? Is it a n = n P(1+r) + P?

Comment: I've added the solution in, but it's the same technique. Also don't forget to upvote if you think the answer was good.

Comment: Thank you so much. But what is t ?

Comment: $t$ for $t$ypo!

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much.