# Find an explicit expression for the general term of a recurrence relation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the formula for the $k$-th term in terms of $k$.
 $$T(0) = T(1) = 1, T(k+2) = 2T(k+1) + 3T(k)$$

First I rearranged the relation:
$$T(k) = \frac{T(k+2)-2T(k+1)}{3}$$

I am not sure where to go from here...

Comment: You don't wanna do that first passage.

Comment: I'll start you off... $$T(k + 2) = 2T(k+1) + 3T(k)$$ then \begin{align}T(k+2) &= 2(2T(k) + 3T(k-1)) + 3T(k)\\&\vdots\end{align} [Example of easier one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236035/find-a-recurrence-relation-for-the-amount-of-money/2236111#2236111)

Comment: I am going to say what  @G. Sassatelli said in a slightly different way: your transformation is not in the sense of history... you can have some difficulty to predict what happens today knowing what will happen tomorrow and the day after...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of responses have provided correct solutions to *your* problem, but not to a more general one. I'll provide a solution for **all** such problems of the form $f_n=af_{n-1}+bf_{n-2}$ with $f(0)=f_0 \ \&\  f(1)=f_1$.

There have been many extensions of the sequence with adjustable (integer) coefficients and different (integer) initial conditions, e.g., $f_n=af_{n-1}+bf_{n-2}$. (You can look up Pell, Jacobsthal, Lucas, Pell-Lucas,  and Jacobsthal-Lucas sequences.) Maynard has extended the analysis to $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, (Ref: Maynard, P. (2008), “Generalised Binet Formulae,” $Applied \ Probability \ Trust$; available at http://ms.appliedprobability.org/data/files/Articles%2040/40-3-2.pdf.)

We have extended Maynard's analysis to include arbitrary $f_0,f_1\in\mathbb{R}$. It is relatively straightforward to show that

$$f_n=\left(f_1-\frac{af_0}{2}\right) \frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta}+\frac{f_0}{2} (\alpha^n+\beta^n) $$

where $\alpha,\beta=(a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4b})/2$.

The result is written in this form to underscore that it is the sum of a Fibonacci-type and Lucas-type Binet-like terms. It will also reduce to the standard Fibonacci and Lucas sequences for $a=b=1 \ \text{and} \ f_0=0, f_1=1$.

So, specializing to your case, we can show that

$$T_n=\frac{3^n+(-1)^n}{2}$$

in agreement with the other responses, but leaving you with a method for all other such problems.

Comment: Very helpful, if you had been sooner I would have given you the answer :). Best answer for me actually

Comment: @J.Doe Just so you know, those can be changed, but I'm not pressing you for it. Thanks for the kind words.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $T(k)= \lambda^k$ ... this give $\lambda^2-2\lambda-3=0$ which has roots $\lambda=-1,3$.
So the general solution will be a linear combination of these ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
T(k)=A(-1)^k+B3^{k}
\end{eqnarray*}
$A $ & $ B$ are easily found from the initial conditions to be $A=B= \frac{1}{2}$
So the solution is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
T(k)=\frac{(-1)^k+3^{k}}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You should ask first to the OP if he has identified a second order recurrence and if the notion of characteristic equation means something to him. I am not certain of that when you see the transformation he has considered...

Comment: Can you give another example of a polynomial like this? Why did you choose $k=2$ and make the other terms negative? How did you decide the form of this polynomial?

Comment: Jean Marie is right ... I should not have launched straight in with the standard solution  ... the general theory of how to solve equations like this can be found here http://people.uncw.edu/tompkinsj/133/recursion/homogeneous.htm

Answer (score 2):

Hint (assuming no knowledge of the standard methods to solve linear homogeneous recurrences):

$$T(k+2) = 2T(k+1) + 3T(k) \;\;\iff\;\; 
T(k+2)+T(k+1)=3\big(T(k+1) + T(k)\big)$$

With $U(k)=T(k)+T(k-1)\,$:

$$U(k+2) = 3 \cdot U(k+1) = 3^2 \cdot U(k) = \cdots = 3^{k+1} \cdot U(1) = 3^{k+1}$$

This reduces the problem to solving the (simpler) recurrence $\;T(k+1)=-T(k) + 3^k\,$.

Comment: Thank you this solution made the most sense to me, I don't know linear algebra yet

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce what you have down to this:
$$T_k=2T_{k-1}+3T_{k-2}$$
You can use a process similar to the one that Binet used when deriving the explicit formula for the fibonacci sequence. First notice that as $n$ approaches infinity, these two ratios approach each other:
$$\frac{T_k}{T_{k-1}}\approx \frac{T_{k-1}}{T_{k-2}}$$
Let us denote the ratio that it approaches by $r$. Then we can say that for large $n$,
$$\frac{T_k}{T_{k-1}}\approx r$$
$$\frac{2T_{k-1}+3T_{k-2}}{T_{k-1}}\approx r$$
$$2+\frac{3T_{k-2}}{T_{k-1}}\approx r$$
$$2+\frac{3}{r}\approx r$$
$$2r+3\approx r^2$$
$$r^2-2r-3\approx 0$$
And, by the quadratic formula,
$$r\approx \frac{2\pm \sqrt{16}}{2}$$
$$r\approx 1\pm 2$$
Let us denote these two values of $r$ with
$$r_+=3$$
and
$$r_-=-1$$
Then we can express $T_k$ as
$$T_k=ar_+^k+br_-^k$$
Where $a$ and $b$ are some constants. Now, to solve for $a$ and $b$, we want to use the first two terms of our sequence; namely, $1$ and $1$, so that
$$1=ar_+^0+br_-^0$$
and
$$1=ar_+^1+br_-^1$$
Now we need only solve this system for $a$ and $b$. Let us simplify this to
$$a+b=1$$
$$3a-b=1$$
And we get $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}$. Then your final formula will be
$$T_k=\frac{1}{2}(3)^k+\frac{1}{2}(-1)^k$$

Comment: How do you know the ratios at the top approach each other? And how do you know to use $T_k = ar_{+}^k + br_{-}^k$?