# Fibonacci sequences and binary number

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I am working on this problem:
We define $S_N$ be all possible combination of the binary number the have following characteristic: 
-if $n=1$, $S_1=1$, and for $n \geq 2$ start all with '01' 
-the numbers have $n$ digits 
-the numbers are never composed by three consecutive numbers (ex 0111)

I tried different approaches, but i notice that
$S_N=2S_{N-1}-S_{N-2}$  and gives Fibonacci numbers. The idea is start with $S_{N-1}$, if we want building $S_{N}$ we must put 1 and 0 for every $S_{n-1}$ (so $2S_{N-1}$) but after we must not consider that strings composed by three consecutive numbers, and it's magically $S_{n-2}$ but i am unable to prove it.

Comment: The recurrence $S_N=2S_{N-1}-S_{N-2}$ doesn't give the Fibonacci numbers (it gives linear functions of $N$).

Comment: ah oke, i will try

Answer (score 0):

I have [previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2264743/find-an-explicit-expression-for-the-general-term-of-a-recurrence-relation/2265991#2265991) described in detail a general solution for **every** sequence of the form $f_n=af_{n-1}+bf_{n-2}$ with arbitrary $f_0,f_1$. The solution can be expressed as

$$
f_n=\left(f_1-\frac{af_0}{2}\right) \frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta}+\frac{f_0}{2} (\alpha^n+\beta^n)
$$

where $\alpha,\beta=(a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4b})/2$.

Specializing to your problem, $S_N=2S_{N-1}-S_{N-2}$ we see that $a,b=2,-1$ so that $\alpha=\beta=a/2=1$. In that case, we need to use the identity

$$
\frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta}=\alpha^{n-1}\beta^0+\alpha^{n-1}\beta^1+\alpha^{n-3}\beta^2+...+\alpha^{0}\beta^{n-1}
$$

which in your case reduces to $\frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta}=N$.

And finally, your solution is

$$S_N=\bigg(S_1-S_0\bigg)N+S_0$$

This solution is in agreement with Greg Martin's comment and has been verified by numerical comparison with the recurrence relation for random $\pm\  S_0 \text{ and } S_1$.

Comment: Assuming OP's recurrence is correct, there's a more direct solution. You could also write $a_N=S_N-S_{N-1}$ and then you have $a_N=a_{N_1}=\dots=a_1$. Thus, $S_N = Na_0 + S_0=N(S_1-S_0)+S_0$.

Comment: @StefanLafon That's true. But my process, though more lengthy, will work on **any** such recurrence. But, alas, your *ad hoc* solution is sweet.

Comment: I like the general solution that you have found.