# How to find a closed-form expression for the sequence $x_n = x_{n-1}(1.1) + 100$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have the sequence $\mathbf{x_n = x_{n-1}(1.1) + 100}$ with $\mathbf{x_0 = 100}$.
How can I calculate $\mathbf{x_n}$ as an explicit function of $\mathbf{n}$?

Comment: Hint: $x_n + 1000 = 1.1 \cdot (x_{n-1} +1000) =...= 1.1^{n}(x_0 + 1000)$

Comment: There is a method ... first solve the homogeneous version $y_n = y_{n-1}\cdot (1.1)$, then undetermined coefficients for this inhomogeneous version.

Comment: @NN2 thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution proffered in the comments is a very nice *ad hoc* solution, but you might be better off learning a method to handle any problem of the sort

$$
x_n=ax_{n-1}+b
$$

The trick is to eliminate $b$ as follows: subtract $x_{n-1}=ax_{n-2}+b$ to obtain

$$
x_n=(a+1)x_{n-1}-ax_{n-2}
$$

which you probably already know how to solve. Using the method [previously described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2264743/find-an-explicit-expression-for-the-general-term-of-a-recurrence-relation/2265991#2265991), I find that the characteristic roots are

$$
\alpha,\beta=\frac{a+1\pm\sqrt{(a+1)^2-4a}}{2}=a,1
$$

and the complete solution is given by

$$
x_n=\frac{(x_1-x_0\beta)\alpha^n-(x_1-x_0\alpha)\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta}
$$

where $x1=ax_0+b$. This solution is valid for arbitrary real and complex $a,b$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I like to solve this
kind of recurrence.
This converts the
recurrence to a
telescoping sum
which is easily evaluated.
This generalizes quite nicely,
which I will leave to you.

If
$x_n=ax_{n-1}+b
$
then,
dividing by
$a^n$,
$\dfrac{x_n}{a^n}
=\dfrac{ax_{n-1}}{a^n}+\dfrac{b}{a^n}
=\dfrac{x_{n-1}}{a^{n-1}}+\dfrac{b}{a^n}
$.

Letting
$y_n
=\dfrac{x_n}{a^n}
$,
this is
$y_n
=y_{n-1}+\dfrac{b}{a^n}
$
or
$y_n-y_{n-1}
=\dfrac{b}{a^n}
$.

Summing from
$1$ to $m$,
this is
$\sum_{n=1}^m(y_n-y_{n-1})
=\sum_{n=1}^m\dfrac{b}{a^n}
$.

The left side is,
since it telescopes,
$y_m-y_0$.
(If you want to start at
$y_1$,
make the sum start at $2$.)

The right side is a geometric series
(unless $a=1$)
so it is

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^m\dfrac{b}{a^n}
&=\dfrac{b}{a}\sum_{n=1}^m(1/a)^{n-1}\\
&=\dfrac{b}{a}\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}(1/a)^{n}\\
&=\dfrac{b}{a}\dfrac{1-1/a^{m}}{1-1/a}\\
&=b\dfrac{1-1/a^{m}}{a-1}\\
&=\dfrac{b}{a-1}-\dfrac{b}{a^m(a-1)}
\end{array}
$

Since
$y_m-y_0
=\dfrac{x_m}{a^m}-x_0
$,

$\dfrac{x_m}{a^m}-x_0
=\dfrac{b}{a-1}-\dfrac{b}{a^m(a-1)}
$
or
$x_m
=a^m(x_0+\dfrac{b}{a-1})-\dfrac{b}{a-1}
$.

If
$a=1$
then
$y_n=x_n$
so
$x_m-x_0
=\sum_{n=1}^m\dfrac{b}{a^n}
=mb
$
so
$x_m
=x_0+mb
$.